# Lost PHP sessions with Internet Explorer and Lighttpd webserver

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session, microsoft-edge, lighttpd

I'm having trouble with PHP sessions with IE11 and Edge (Windows 10) connecting to a Lighttpd web-server.

Consider this code:

```
if (PHP_SESSION_NONE === session_status()) {
    session_start();
}

$x = isset($_SESSION['bob'])? $_SESSION['bob']  : 'nothing';
echo 'The Session has started, bob is set to ' . $x .'<br/>';

$_SESSION['bob'] = 'hope';

echo 'The Session ID is ' . session_id() .'<br/>';
```

When I browse to test.php - containing the above code - using Chrome, shut down Chrome, reopen Chrome, and then browse back to this page it displays:

```
The Session has started, bob is set to hope
The Session ID is 6d2jbpmrrlrqt96h2nd19ua160
```

IE11 and Edge will however display:

The Session has started, bob is set to nothing
  The Session ID is 35k87vgdt7t41q4lkphq815hq1

Why are IE11 and Edge dropping the session?

**This problem is also happening on WAMP Apache, so although I've seen references to Lighttpd being a potential cause ([Internet Explorer, jQuery, session lost php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103507/internet-explorer-jquery-session-lost-php), ) I'm not convinced.

** Also, Fiddler shows a new session ID with each IE\Edge connection.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Was session_start() on the top of every page?  I personally like to put it with my SQL stuff because all of my SQL pages will likely also be needing session data.

Comment: For testing there's only one page with session_start at the top. In the real code it's included from a shared file required by most of the other php scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a cookie lifetime to the session using **session_set_cookie_params** like:

```
    if (PHP_SESSION_NONE === session_status()) {
    session_set_cookie_params(60*60*24*7);
    session_start();
}
```

solves the problem: the session persists after the browser is closed and reopened.

The php documentation http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime states:

> session.cookie_lifetime specifies the lifetime of the cookie in seconds which is sent to the browser. The value 0 means "until the browser is closed." Defaults to

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Which raises the question of why it works in Chrome (45.0.2454.101 m)? But that's another question...

**Footnote:** Although the max lifetime value for a session cookie would appear to be 2,147,483,647 the max value for "session.gc_maxlifetime" seems to be 65535; and setting lifetime  to larger values stopped my sessions from working.